# Expectation value of an operator error: Composition is not defined over operators of different dimensions,

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, qiskit, programming

I am trying to calculate the expectation value of a customized operator on two similar but differently constructed states $\phi = \phi_2 =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |001⟩ + |011⟩\right)$ which consist of more qubits than the operator. (via Qiskit)

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.aqua.operators import CircuitOp, state_fns, Zero, One

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.z(0)
circuit.z(1)

op = CircuitOp(circuit)

psi = QuantumCircuit(3)
psi.h(1)
psi.x(2)
psi = state_fns.CircuitStateFn(circuit)
psi2 = 1 / np.sqrt(2) * ((Zero ^ Zero ^ One) + (Zero ^ One ^ One))


print('Expectation for phi:', psi.adjoint().compose(op).compose(psi).eval().real)  # Expectation for phi: 1.0
print('Expectation for phi2:', psi2.adjoint().compose(op).compose(psi2).eval().real) # Error
```

The second expectation raises an error:
`ValueError: Composition is not defined over Operators of different dimensions, 3 and 2, respectively.`

**Why is this happening? Why the first expectation is executed fine but not the second one?**

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I think there is a little mistake in the way you define `psi`. Indeed, you first create it as a 3-qubits circuit and then "erase" this by doing `psi = state_fns.CircuitStateFn(circuit)`, meaning it will be exactly the same as the operator you defined right before, `op`. You can check the circuit you create via an operator using for example `psi.primitive.draw()` if you want to see! This is why your code worked for `psi` but not for `psi2`.

Then, Qiskit won't do the composition of operators that don't have the same size because it is not mathematically possible with matrices. May I suggest adding a third qubit on `op` without adding any gates on it, this way `op` will have the same size as `psi` and `psi2` and your code will run without errors since all the operators will have the same size!
I hope this will help you :)